# Math Analysis Courses online

Tags: real-analysis

Can somebody recommend me respectable Math Analysis courses online?
I am a student and I took real analysis course in my university, but I am unsatisfied with the quality of that course. I am even considering switching university because I cannot get descent analysis courses there. But first I want to try take one on line.
Any thoughts?
Thank you in advance.
Marina

Comment: Just curious, but what made the analysis course at your university so unsatisfying?

Comment: Firstly, we just touched many topics on the surface without really studying and feeling them. Secondly, our professor constantly got lost in his/her own proofs and definitions, I felt like I was on the ship with a drunk captain. I want to go into this magic world of analysis with a "native".

Comment: Ok, that's understandable!  It definitely helps to have a seasoned professor teach any analysis-type course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look into MIT's OpenCourseware offerings. (Mathematical Analysis encompasses A LOT!)

See the following courses that are more on the foundational level:

- [Analysis I](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100a-introduction-to-analysis-fall-2012/)
- [Analysis II](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-101-analysis-ii-fall-2005/)
- [Real Analysis](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-100c-real-analysis-fall-2012/).

See also the math course offerings from [saylor.org.](http://www.saylor.org/majors/mathematics/) You'll find links to Real Analysis I, II, and Complex Analysis that you can check out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked it out. Can't wait to start.

Comment: You're welcome, Marina. I love your enthusiasm!